# always return some raws in UNION even if the condition doesnt match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, union

I have a stored proc which unions some data and returns back. At max that SP will return me 3 rows meeting the where condition.

Is there a way i can force the SP to return the blank row if there is no data present which matches the condition?

This is how my SP looks like:

```
SELECT Top 1 Col1, 'FirstResult' FROM Table T1
       where SomeColumn='whatever'

UNION ALL

SELECT Top 1 Col2, 'SecondResult' FROM Table T1
       where SomeColumn='whatever'

UNION ALL

SELECT Top 1 Col3, 'ThirdResult' FROM Table T1
       where SomeColumn='whatever'
```

I want to always return me 3 rows regardless even if the condition doesnt match. Of course data will be empty or `NULL` in the resultset.

Comment: That sounds like something that should be done in the GUI, not in a stored proc (or even the business logic of your code).  Just my $.02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go here to demonstrate that the query in this answer works with no rows: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51d1c/3

With 1 row in YourTable: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad1e8/1

Here is a procedure that should return what you are looking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pExample_Get3ForcedRows
    @FirstMatch VARCHAR(50)
    ,@SecondMatch VARCHAR(50)
    ,@ThirdMatch VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ForceTable TABLE
(
    MatchColumn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT @ForceTable (MatchColumn) VALUES (@FirstMatch),(@SecondMatch),(@ThirdMatch)

SELECT
    T.Col1
    , T.ResultColumn
FROM @ForceTable F
LEFT JOIN YourTable T
    ON T.SomeColumn = F.MatchColumn

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table (Col1 varchar, String2 varchar)

IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table T1 WHERE SomeColumn='whatever')>0 )
  INSERT INTO @table
  SELECT Top 1 Col1, 'FirstResult' FROM Table T1 WHERE SomeColumn='whatever'
ELSE
  INSERT INTO @table
  SELECT NULL AS Col1, ''

IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table T1 WHERE SomeColumn='whatever')>0 )
  INSERT INTO @table
  SELECT Top 1 Col2, 'secondResult' FROM Table T1 WHERE SomeColumn='whatever'
ELSE
  INSERT INTO @table
  SELECT NULL AS Col2, ''

IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table T1 WHERE SomeColumn='whatever')>0 )
  INSERT INTO @table
  SELECT Top 1 Col3, 'thirdResult' FROM Table T1 WHERE SomeColumn='whatever'
ELSE
  INSERT INTO @table
  SELECT NULL AS Col3, ''

RETURN @table
```

Don't know if there is a more elegant version, but this should work.